# reshape in R: what is "colsplit, melt, recast"

Tags: r

New R user:
I get the following error when I try to add "reshape" to my library

Attaching package: ‘reshape’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:reshape2’:

```
colsplit, melt, recast
```

So commands like "untable" wont run. Can someone help?

Comment: You can run with `reshape2::colsplit`

Comment: do you really need both `reshape` and `reshape2`? What exactly are you doing? It would be nice if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it clear how you are making your package.

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning (or information).